# Subset Sum represented as a perfect number

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Can we form a set of $29$ distinct integer elements such that every subset of elements possible has a sum which is a *perfect power*? A *perfect power* is a positive integer that can be represented a p^q for some positive integers p(>1) and q(>1).

Comment: _"...a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors..."_ - Wikipedia
This is completely different to the definition you've given.

Comment: with your definition every number is perfect

Comment: This is just a term defined by me. It has nothing to do with the wikipedia definition.

Comment: You have to add some restrictions on $p,q$ since $p^1=p$ for every positive integer,also do you mean $29$ distinct elements?And are they integers?

Comment: Edited the question.